# What is the difference between 柔韧 and 灵活?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between 柔韧 and 灵活 ?
Both mean flexible (and both are adjectives, as I see).
Which one suits more to “schedule” for instance - “flexible schedule” ?
And which suit to “hamstrings”.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

柔韧 relates to a person's **physical flexibility** to bend/stretch, for example, "她的身體像草般的柔韧" means "her body is as flexible as grass".

灵活 is the agility of a person's **body parts coordination**, **brain function/thought process**, and the flexibility of a thing's **making direction changes**. Examples are: "她的身手佷灵活 - her body parts coordination is very flexible", "她的腦筋佷灵活 - she has a very quick flexible mind", and "灵活的政策 - flexible policy".

"flexible schedule" - **灵活的**时间表/计划

"flexible hamstrings" - **灵活的**腿筋

Answer (score 1):

1. 灵活: 快捷;不死板: nimble, quick, not rigid
2. 灵活: 不拘泥于固有模式,善于变通: not bound by fixed patterns, good at adapting

柔韧: 柔软而坚韧: soft and strong but pliable

a flexible schedule:
灵活性的计划表
可变通的日程表
灵活的计划表

Answer (score 1):

柔韧 means "soft yet tough / tenacious." You can use 柔韧 to describe toilet paper. It is a pure physical property.

灵活 is "agile, nimble." It can be physical, mental, mechanical, etc. A gymnast can be 灵活, so can a monkey or rabbit. Even reactions can be described as 灵活.

"Flexible" doesn't quite match up with either.

Answer (score 0):

- **柔韧**(soft, firm and stretchable) = **flexible** -  describes **body** or **muscl**e.

Example:

Ballet dancers' **bodies** are very **flexible** (**柔韧**)

Boxers' **muscles** are very **flexible** (**柔韧**)

- **灵活**(agile and lively) = **agile**/ **flexible** - describes **moveability** or **agility**

Example:

My wrist has recovered and become **flexible** (**灵活**) again, (I can **turn it in wide angles** again)

Footballers' movements are very **agile** (**灵活**) (they can **change directions quickly**)

> Which one suits more to “schedule”?

**flexible** schedule = **灵活**的时间表 (it can be flexibly changed)